# Quick Sort an Array of Records (Struct)

Tags: c++, c

I am new to C programming and am trying to quick sort an array of records. I'm not sure if I am sending the Record to the function properly but my error is

> error: conversion from "TaxRecord*" to non-scalar type "TaxRecord" requested
>   error: no match for "operator<" in "*(table + ((unsigned int)(((unsigned int)left) * 104u))) < pivot"

```
void qsort(TaxRecord table,int start,int finish);

qsort(theEmployees[i],0,i);

void qsort(TaxRecord table[],int start,int finish) {
    int left = start,
    right = finish;
    TaxRecord pivot = table[((start+finish)/2)];
    TaxRecord temp = table;

    while (left < right) {
        // find left candidate
        while (table[left]  < pivot)
            left++; 
        // find right candidate 
        while (table[right] > pivot)
            right--; 
        if (left <= right) {
            int temp = table[left];
            table[left] = table[right];
            table[right] = temp;
            left++;
            right--;
        } 
    } // while left < right

    if (start < right)
        qsort(table,start,right);
    if (left < finish)
        qsort(table,left,finish);
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with the standard library implementation?

Comment: declared `void qsort(TaxRecord table,int start,int finish);` but implemented `void qsort(TaxRecord table[],int start,int finish);`? Don't know if this the problem. Also, if TaxRecord is a class/struct and then you must define the < operator to use it. If it is a class then I'd also recommend that you not copy it all the time but rather use references or pointers

Comment: The c++ solution would be to define the < operator and just use a vector and std::sort ...

Comment: @PeterT: That is indeed the problem the error message discusses.  Make that an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Your function prototype doesn't match the function declaration.

```
void qsort(TaxRecord table,int start,int finish);
void qsort(TaxRecord table[],int start,int finish)
```

2) You call the function with what appears to be a single array element instead of the array itself.

```
qsort(theEmployees[i],0,i);
```

3) You attempt to assign an array to a single `TaxRecord` variable.

```
TaxRecord temp = table;
```

4) You attempt to use an `int` temporary while swapping `TaxRecord` elements.

```
int temp = table[left];
table[left] = table[right];
table[right] = temp;
```

5) The error message sounds like there isn't a defined `operator<` for your `TaxRecord` type.

My suggestion: instead of fixing your code just use the library `qsort` or `std::sort`, depending on whether this is C or C++.

Comment: you don't know 2) for a fact, it might be a `TaxRecord **` but you are probably right.

Comment: @PeterT, it is an assumption on my part but the variable `i` being both the correct `theEmployees` subscript and the size of the `TaxRecord` array is very suspicious.

Comment: @Blastfurnace - Thank you a ton!!! You pointed out a few of my Rookie mistakes plus got my brain in the right place to find a few more! TaxRecord is an Array of Records i.e. typedef struct TaxRecord{...}

Answer (score 1):

You declared

```
void qsort(TaxRecord table,int start,int finish);
```

but implemented

```
void qsort(TaxRecord table[],int start,int finish);
```

Also, if TaxRecord is a class/struct and then you must define the `<` operator to use it on it. I'd also recommend that you not copy it all the time but rather use references or pointers. If you want to keep it pure C then you have to pass the function a function pointer to a compare function like this:

```
void qsort(void *data,int start, int finish, int(*compare)(const void *, const void *));
```